# Windows UDP sending problems

Tags: windows, udp

I have a weird behaviour on windows. I have 2 processes that are talking to each other on UDP protocol.
Scenario: 1 of the proceeses is up and the other is not. The process try to send udp message towards the one that is down. The one that is up gets from OS or soemthing else a signal for the socket to read as it got message from the other process.

How come ?

Comment: Please try editing that last sentence as it is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends a signal on the same port, but it not a real message that was sent from the other application. When trying to read it u get an excpetion of number 10054, connection reset.